MFC worker Thread Synchronisation
I'm using MFC threading:
both main thread and worker thread are using the same function ReceiveResponse().
and I change myMaster->configDone so that the worker thread executes different work based on myMaster->configDone value.
the problem is that I may change myMaster->configDone value in my main thread, but the worker thread sometimes would receive data even when the myMaster->configDone != tComSts::COM_CFG_DONE. in my opinion because it hasnt finish the loop before that the main thread changed the value of myMaster->configDone.
what should I do in this case please?
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxmt.h>

#define THREAD_DELAY_MS 100

class myClass;

WorkerThread::WorkerThread(myClass *pClassSession)
    : m_pSession(pSession), m_hThread(nullptr)
{
}

WorkerThread::~WorkerThread()
{
}

BOOL WorkerThread::InitInstance()
{  
m_hThread = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunction, m_pSession, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, CREATE_SUSPENDED);

    m_hThread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

int WorkerThread::ExitInstance()
{
    return CWinThread::ExitInstance();
}

using ModeFieldBits = SetDaqListModePacket::ModeFieldBits;

UINT WorkerThread::ThreadFunction(LPVOID pParam)
{
    myClass *myMaster = reinterpret_cast<myClass *>(pParam);

    if (nullptr != myMaster)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (tComSts::COM_CFG_DONE == myMaster->configDone)
            {
                st_msg rmsg = {0};
                myMaster->ReceiveResponse(true, TIMEOUT_RECEIVE, &rmsg);
            }
            else if (tComSts::COM_CFG_NONE == myMaster->configDone)
            {
                //do some work
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


You need to protect shared variables from concurrent access across threads, such as by using a mutex, condition variable, interlocked/atomic, etc.

Just learn how to use std::thread, (std::mutex, std::scoped_lock/std::unique_lock and std::condition_variable). They have been since C++ are far easier to use and less error prone. I have used MFC a lot and I can speak from my own experience it is a blessing when you can leave it behind.

Win32 offers the Critical Section mechanism, which is faster and easier to use than a mutex - only has the limitation of being able to serialize threads of the same application (which is very much OK in most cases). Lock it, get or set the variable in question and then release it. You could also consider objects like a manual-reset Event. it acts as a "synchronization boolean"; the main thread can set or clear it and the worker thread wait on it (by trying to "lock" it) or not.

Another way to handle this is to post messages between the threads, where both threads have message queues in both. Most MFC dialogs have a built in one which you easily can extend to handle user events where you pass your data along. Try avoid synchronization if you can, it can affect performance in a bad way if you do it wrong.
